# Dynamically change content of sonata_type_model field

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I use Sonata admin bundle and type sonata_type_model for some field on page.

How I can dynamically change list of elements in this field? I need change content of this field depending on the value in another field.

E.g., in field with type sonata_type_model are showed all categories of something. And in another field on page I can select gender (M or F). How I could automatically change content of field with categories if value of gender was selected?
In this example for field with categories applying type sonata_type_model is important because this type allow select existing categories and enter new category.

Answer (score 0):

You should use form events to handle the dynamic generation of your form

[Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms)

**Sample**

Function **configureFormFields** in Admin class

```
$formBuilder = $formMapper->getFormBuilder();
        $currentUser = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage');
$formMapper->add('driverCompany',null,array('class' =>'XXXXXBundle:Company'));
                $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Company $oCompany = null, $defaultCompany) {
                    $company = null === $oCompany ? $defaultCompany : $oCompany;
                    $form->add(
                        'zones',
                        null,
                        array(
                            'class' => 'XXXXXXBundle:Zone',
                            'label' => 'Zones',
                            'multiple' => true,
                            'required' => false,
                            'placeholder' => '',
                            'query_builder' => function (ZoneRepository $zr) use ($company) {
                                return $zr
                                    ->createQueryBuilder('z')
                                    ->where('z.companyZone = ?1')
                                    ->setParameter(1, $company);
                            },
                        )
                    );
                };
                $formBuilder->addEventListener(
                    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $defaultCompany) {
                        $data = $event->getData();

                        if ($data !== null) {
                            if ($data->getDriverCompany() === null) {
                                $oCompany = null;
                            } else {
                                $oCompany = $data->getDriverCompany();
                            }
                            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $oCompany, $defaultCompany);
                        }
                    }
                );

                $formBuilder->get('driverCompany')->addEventListener(
                    FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
                    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $defaultCompany) {

                        $oCompany = $event->getForm()->getData();
                        $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $oCompany, $defaultCompany);
                    }
                );
```